Does an FM Loop Antenna's Loop diameter affect reception?
I live 75 miles from one of my favorite station's broadcast tower (91.1 FM), and I would like to get better reception.
Currently, I am using a NAD 4150 Tuner with a T style antenna. I ran it out a nearby window and stuck it to the exterior of the side of the house (second floor).
The tuner has options for a 75ohm external too.
I'd like to use an external antenna so as not take away the aesthetic of the room.
I was looking at 2 different external omnidirectional "loop" antenna, thinking I would mount in my attic.
One has a 21.5" diameter: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B006SLV25C/
The other seems to have a shorter diameter, 17.75" https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00DHHOZBI/
Does diameter affect the antenna gain or reception for a configuration like this?
I also read this post, but it doesn't really help me choose one of the above products, or understand if the diameter of the "loop" will matter. Also, the picture in this post doesn't match the products above, so I am not even sure if the post is talking about the same product type.
I considered looking into a directional antenna too, but to be honest, I'd be too lazy to move it when needed.

I know this is not what you're asking about, and I do apologize for side-tracking this discussion, but even under ideal conditions, the sound quality of an broadcast FM reception would be worse than the online stream; and over 75 miles… just play https://jazzfm91.streamb.live/SB00009 on your phone (or Raspberry Pi or media center or sonos receiver or whatever you like to connect to your hifi receiver's line in) and you'd be better off, acoustically. But your technical question is valid and interesting.

by the way, maybe if it helps searching for antennas: the products you linked to might be called "loop antennas" (because, well, it's correct that they have loop shape), but I think electrically I'd call them "folded dipoles bent in a near-circle" or something similar. The fact that one reviewer of your larger antenna says they can operate it well in an "S" shape instead of an O-with-a-slot shape really suggests the larger diameter here is beneficial, but mostly because if you know from which direction your radio station comes, you're better of with a large linear dimension. So, if your T-

shaped antenna (probably a straight dipole, or a folded dipole that has not been bent in a circular shape!) has a width of roughly 1.5m, then that's as good as this antenna principle would get for your use case.

Thanks for the info. The hi-fi I am using to play the radio is all analog. I have ran a line from a computer to play internet radio, but I do like the analog tuner, especially cause it is just set and forget. Click some physical buttons on the devices and it works. I've looked into streaming devices, but I don't want to interact with a screen to use the stereo.

as said, I can fully appreciate that. But if that's the case, are you really sure that a better antenna would solve the issue?

I am not sure a better antenna would help as I have little experience using them. I am making the assumption that elevating the antenna to the attic or roof line will help. This question is all about choosing the best antenna for the job.

Antenna dimensions are important to an antenna's gain, but the question is what is the gain of each of those antennas?
Your STELLAR LABS (30-2435) claims to have 4dB gain, but I couldn't find a gain figure for the other antenna you listed.  Both of those antennas are omni directional, so they should receive stations from all directions.
I would get a beam or Yagi antenna designed for FM; it will be very directional, and may attenuate signals of stations that are in other directions, but it has a 7dB gain in the direction it's pointed in, and that a doubling of signal compared to 4dB, and who knows what you have now.
FM Beam Antenna
Maybe you can find a cheap TV antenna rotor to have it spin around if you need to.
Some of the Yagi TV Antennas are designed for FM reception, and with a splitter, you can receive over the air digital TV as well.
You could always add an amplifier as well.
Good luck, let us know what you do and how it works out.

the gain of a Yagi antenna depends on the number of its directors, and on how close to the design frequency you're operating it; it drops more rapidly as you go below than as you go above design frequeny; it's not generally 7dB.

I ran a RG6 line up the wall and into the attic over the weekend. I added the STELLAR LABS (30-2435) antenna in its stock configuration. I walked it all along the attic and spun it in all directions while watching the signal strength on my tuner. The tuner signal strength meter is not that sensitive. 1-5. The signal strength didn't improve. One positive, is that the ugly 300ohm T shaped antenna no longer has to hang in sight. Anecdotally, while listening this week, I think there is less noise and static on the station, but I realize that may just be biased.

What's next? Not sure. Going to live with the antenna for the week or so. I'm not sure if moving the antenna to a 3' mast on the corner of the roof is worth the effort/exposure. Moving it higher by 10' didn't help. I am still happy with the $30 investment at this point. I may try a DIY yagi, from some metal tubing I have laying around the workshop. Or I may try changing the configuration of the STELLAR LABS (30-2435) to be in an S formation and see if it helps.
